# Java class Vectors is running too slow

Tags: java

Here are my three classes as follows:

Array_List.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Array_List {
public long startTime, difference = 0;
public ArrayList<Integer> a;

    public Array_List() {
        a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public void buildArray() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (difference <= 10000) {
            int r = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            a.add(r);
            difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        }
    }
}
```

This class creates an array list and times its creation.

In the next java class I am using the size of Array_List to initialize the size of a vector class. I want them both to be the same size so I can compare the speeds. Since I made the size of Array_list dependent on its speed. I can then compare Vectors using the same size.

Vectors.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Vectors {

    public long startTime, difference = 0;
    public Vector<Integer> a;

    public Vectors(int size) {
        a = new Vector<Integer>(size);
    }

    public void buildVectors() {
        int i=0;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(i<=a.size()) {
            int r = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            a.add(r);
            difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This next class will run both methods.

performanceOfArrays.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class performanceOfArrays {

    public static Array_List arrayList;
    public static Vectors vectors;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        arrayList = new Array_List();
        arrayList.buildArray();

        S.ystem.out.println("Testing the speed of an array list:");

        System.out.print("The speed of composing an array list with " + arrayList.getSize());
        System.out.print(" integers is " + arrayList.getSpeed() + " seconds.");

        vectors = new Vectors(arrayList.getSize());
        vectors.buildVectors();

        System.out.print("Testing the speed of a vector:");

        System.out.println("The speed of composing a vector with " + vectors.getSize());
        System.out.print(" integers is " + vectors.getSpeed() + " seconds.");
    }
}
```

I keep running into memory and speed problems with Vectors.java. I know it has to do with my buildVectors() method. It seems as though the method will not stop.

Any help on what to do would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear - what are you trying to accomplish with `i` inside of `buildVectors`?

Comment: First, your benchmark is invalid cause the JVM does optimizations while running, so it gets speed up, you must test then separatedly, do that and come back with the new results (also add the results).. Also, theres no point on storing "difference" inside the loop, move it to outside

Comment: *Why* are you using [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)? It's an old mostly obsolete class. The javadoc even says: *"If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to **use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`**"*. As for thread-safe implementations, you should use the newer [concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) implementations added in Java 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

In your code for vector you use `while (i < a.size())` but then you call `a.add()` which adds element to vector and increments its size. So your while loop never ends.

If you know number of elements you want to add beforehand you'd better use `for` loop for that.

BTW vector has all methods marked as synchronized so it will be slower then arraylist anyway